# about plotting process -- a further question about "A problem in Mathematica 8 with function declaration"

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Related [A problem in Mathematica 8 with function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046626/a-problem-in-mathematica-8-with-function-declaration)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

model = 4/Sqrt[3] - a1/(x + b1) - a2/(x + b2)^2 - a3/(x + b3)^4;
fit = {a1 -> 0.27, a2 -> 0.335, a3 -> -0.347, b1 -> 4.29, b2 -> 0.435,
b3 -> 0.712};

functionB1[x_] = model /. fit;
functionB2[x_] := model /. fit;
```

The evaluation difference between functionB1 and functionB2 can be revealed by `Trace` command in mma, as below:

```
functionB1[Sqrt[0.2]] // Trace
functionB2[Sqrt[0.2]] // Trace
```

I have no question about functionB1. **what puzzles me is that** because `functionB2[Sqrt[0.2]]` doesn't even gives a numeric result but gives a function of x `4/Sqrt[3] - 0.335/(0.435 + x)^2 + 0.347/(0.712 + x)^4 - 0.27/(
 4.29 + x)`, and then how its plot `Plot[functionB2[Sqrt[x]], {x, 0, 1}]` is possible?

I mean when you run `Plot[functionB2[Sqrt[x]], {x, 0, 1}]`, what happens inside mma is:

x takes a number, say, 0.2, then 0.2 is finally passed to functionB2, but functionB2 gives a function, not a number. Then how is the following figure generated?

[image]

And its trace result ( `Plot[functionB2[Sqrt[x]], {x, 0, 1}] // Trace` ) seems very unreadable. I wonder the clear plotting process of functionB2. Can anybody show it?

thanks~ :)

Answer (score 5):

`SetDelayed` acts as a scoping construction. Arguments are localized if necessary. Any variables that *explicitly* match the arguments are bound within this scope, others are not.

```
In[78]:= a[x_] := x^2 + b
         b = x^4;

(* the first x^2 is explicitly present and bound to the argument. 
   The x in x^4 present via b is not bound *)

In[80]:= a[x]

Out[80]= x^2 + x^4 (* this is what you would expect *)

In[81]:= a[y]

Out[81]= x^4 + y^2 (* surprise *)

In[82]:= a[1]

Out[82]= 1 + x^4 (* surprise *)
```

So, what you could do is one of two things:

- Use `Evaluate`: `functionB2[x_] := Evaluate[model /. fit];`
- Make dependence of `model` on x explicit:

  In[68]:= model2[x_] = 
    4/Sqrt[3] - a1/(x + b1) - a2/(x + b2)^2 - a3/(x + b3)^4;

  In[69]:= functionB3[x_] := model2[x] /. fit;

  In[85]:= functionB3[Sqrt[0.2]]

  Out[85]= 2.01415

**Edit** because of question update
Because of your definition of functionB2 any argument value yields the same result, as explained above:

```
In[93]:= functionB2[1]

Out[93]= 4/Sqrt[3] - 0.335/(0.435 + x)^2 + 0.347/(0.712 + 
   x)^4 - 0.27/(4.29 + x)

In[94]:= functionB2["Even a string yields the same ouput"]

Out[94]= 4/Sqrt[3] - 0.335/(0.435 + x)^2 + 0.347/(0.712 + 
   x)^4 - 0.27/(4.29 + x)
```

However, this expression contains x's and therefore it can get a numerical value if we provide a numerical value for x:

```
In[95]:= functionB2["Even a string yields the same ouput"] /. x -> 1

Out[95]= 2.13607
```

Well, this basically what `Plot` does too. This is why you still get a plot.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! Shouldn't you remind me of the three things we normally do?  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Sjoerd. So, the first step mma deals with the plot command is: evaluating the function to be plotted? I previously thought that the fist step when plotting a function is x takes a value, then the function catch this value and returs a result. If this were right, then func = Sin[x]; Plot[func,{x,0,1}] will never yield a figure. Sorry for this stupid misunderstanding. -_-!

Comment: @FreshApple Plot holds its arguments (it has the `HoldAll` attribute). That's why you have to use `Plot[Evaluate[Table[Sin[k x], {k, 1, 5}]], {x, 0, Pi}]` instead of `Plot[Table[Sin[k x], {k, 1, 5}], {x, 0, Pi}]` (at least, if you want the different graphs have different colors). Your func example works because when `Plot` starts throwing values at func it sets up an environment in which x gets its successive values and in which func is evaluated as long as mma knows transformations rules for it. In this case func -> Sin[x] -> Sin of whatever value x has in this environment.

Comment: Sjoerd, congratulations on 3000 rep!

Answer (score 5):

The definition:

```
functionB2[x_] := model /. fit
```

is an instruction to Mathematica to replace all future occurrences of an expression that looks like `functionB2[x_]` with the result of substituting the value of the argument for every occurrence of `x` in the expression `model /. fit`.  But there *are* no occurrences of `x` in `model /. fit`: the only symbols in that expression are `model` and `fit` (and, technically, `ReplaceAll`).  Therefore, the definition returns a fixed result, `model /. fit`, irrespective of the argument.  Indeed, the definition could just simply be:

```
functionB2a[] := model /. fit
```

If you plot `functionB2a[]`, you will get the same result as if you plotted `functionB2[anything]`.  Why?  Because `Plot` will evaluate that expression while varying the symbol `x` over the plot range.  It so happens that `model /. fit` evaluates to an expression involving that symbol, so you get the exhibited plot.

Now consider `functionB1`:

```
functionB1[x_] = model /. fit
```

It too says to replace all occurrences of `x` on the right-hand side -- but this time the right-hand side is evaluated *before* the definition is established.  The result of evaluating `model /. fit` is an expression that *does* contain the symbol `x`, so now the definition is sensitive to the passed argument value.  The net result is as if the function were defined thus:

```
functionB1a[x_] := 4/Sqrt[3]-0.335/(0.435+x)^2+0.347/(0.712+x)^4-0.27/(4.29+x)
```

So, if you plot `functionB1[Sqrt[x]]`, the `Plot` command will see the expression:

```
4/Sqrt[3]-0.335/(0.435 +Sqrt[x])^2+0.347/(0.712 +Sqrt[x])^4-0.27/(4.29 +Sqrt[x])
```

**Formal Symbols**

When establishing definitions using `SetDelayed`, the name of the formal argument (`x` in this case) is independent of any occurrences of the same symbol outside of the definition.  Such definitions can use any other symbol, and still generate the same result.  On the other hand, definitions established using `Set` (such as `functionB1`) *rely* on the result of evaluating the right-hand side containing the same symbol as the formal argument.  This can be a source of subtle bugs as one must take care not use symbols that accidentally have pre-existing down-values.  The use of formal symbols (described in [Letters and Letter-like Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html)) for argument names can help manage this problem.

Comment: The situation is actually somewhat more complex since both `Set` and `SetDelayed` are scoping constructs and sometimes rename their pattern variables, while of course they will not be renamed for the r.h.s. of `Set`. This may not be apparent for the top-level definitions (where such renamings are not so aggressive), but this causes subtle problems for example inside `Module`, as discussed e.g. in this thread: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/May/msg00102.html. My own conclusion is that such implicit constructs as `f[x_]=a/.b` are not reliable and should not be used.

Comment: @Leonid Agreed.  There are situations when it is useful to establish a generated definition, but it would be safer to set up such definitions using other strategies, e.g. ones that involve `With`, localized symbols and/or formal symbols.  As you say in the cited post, the `Set` strategy can be very useful in an interactive context, but it is another one of those things (like evaluation leakage) that is hard to get correct when writing library code.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I do not mind doing the "scope surgery" and manipulating the variable bindings in scoping constructs, but my feeling is that such manipulations generally fall under 2 distinct categories - well-defined (those where you have the full control over the result), and not well-defined (those where you only have partial control). And I try to avoid the latter, while the example under discussion clearly belongs to it. Also, in my experience, it was always possible to achieve the goal with methods available within the first category.

Answer (score 2):

You can understand what is going on by trying:

```
Table[functionB2[Sqrt[y]],{y,0.5,.5,.5}]
Table[functionB2[Sqrt[x]],{x,0.5,.5,.5}]
(*
{4/Sqrt[3] - 0.335/(0.435+ x)^2 + 0.347/(0.712+ x)^4 - 0.27/(4.29+ x)}
{2.03065}
*)
```

What is getting replaced is the `x` inside the definition of functionB2, not a formal argument.

**Edit**

The plot you are getting is not what you want. The `Sqrt[x]` is disregarded in `functionB2[...]` and the implicit x is replaced, as you can see here:

[image]